# SVG not displaying on website

Tags: html, svg

I am trying to use a SVG and nothing is being displayed. The png version of the file works as expected.

```
<img src="typewriter.svg" alt="typewriter svg">
```

I have searched and there seems to be a issue with chrome and SVGs but I don't think thats the issue here.

Comment: Do you have a link to the page in question?

Comment: Check what mediatype the server sends, it must be 'image/svg+xml' for it to work properly. Another thing I've heard is that chrome has had an issue with in the past is when the same svg is used both as an <img> and as a css background image on the same page, is that the case here?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how it should work:

```
<object data="typewriter.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
  <img src="typewriter.png" />
</object>
```